# Incrementing numbers doesn't give an error

Tags: php, numbers, increment

How come this code below echo's 2 and does not give an error, does it just ignore `+1+2+3+4` ?

I've searched but couldn't find an answer.

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$i+++1+2+3+4;
echo $i;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That line:

```
$i+++1+2+3+4;
```

Says:

- Increment `$i`
- Add the value of `$i` *pre* increment to `+1+2+3+4`, but *don't* store the result anywhere.

Hence `$i == 2`.

If you wouldn't want it to be ignored, you should store the result:

```
$i = $i+++1+2+3+4;
```

Answer (score 2):

All is fine. You just forgot the assignment, so `i` is affected only by `++` operator:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$x = $i+++1+2+3+4;
echo "{$i} vs "{$x}";
```

would return

```
2 vs 11
```

Answer (score 2):

You never assign the completed operation anywhere:

These two are functionally equivalent:

```
$i++;
$i = $i + 1;
```

both will increment `$i` by 1, and save that incremented value in `$i`

With `$i+++1+2+3+4` you're essentially executing

```
  ($i++) + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
```

which is

```
 $i = $i + 1;
 1 + 2 + 3 + 4; // useless, result not stored anywhere
```

so which increments `$i` by 1, saves that to `$i`, then does the other additions. But since those aren't being saved anywhere, the result is thrown away.

if you had

```
php > $i = 1;
php > $i = $i+++1+2+3+4;
      ^^^^^----add this
php > echo $i;
11
```

then it would have worked as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

`$i++` means add 1 to `$i`.
and like python, the `+1+2+3+4` means add the value of `$i` pre increment to `+1+2+3+4` but don't store it anywhere.(so no memory address or anything like that...).
so what you get is just `$i==2`